# Another Motion Problem: Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It takes a ship $6$ hours to travel downstream between two piers, and $8$ hours upstream. If the water flows at a speed of $2.5$ mph, at what speed will the ship travel in still water?

It's a bit confusing to me..

Comment: I don't appreciate hit and run downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $x$ be the boat speed in still water: $6(x+2.5) = 8(x-2.5)$

Comment: A very generous hint indeed.

Comment: you know... some student still struggling with "word problem"....

Comment: I understand. I didn't mean it negatively, I meant it as the user should be very grateful you're willing to help.